# Influxdb 2: Cannot sign in

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I've managed to install influxdb2 and login to the web ui at localhost:8086 with the default username/pass admin/admin. But when I try to login now with the same credentials i get an error saying "Could not sign in" as shown here: [image] Running `systemctl status influxdb` gives me this output: [image] This persists after reboots and reinstalls of influxdb. Is there some way to hard reset the password or to disable the authentification?

Answer (score 8):

You can reset your InfluxDB 2 administrator password by recovering a admin token if you have access to the installation filesystem.

Find influxd.bolt on the host or in the container: /var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.bolt

Search this mixed text and binary json file for strings like your known username or `token`.

```
cat /var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.bolt | strings | grep "admin's Token"
```

```
{"id":"1234567898000000",
"token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
"status":"active",
"description":"admin's Token",
```

With an admin-privileged token, you can update the password with the Influx Command Line Interface (CLI) command `influx user password`. For example:

```
$ docker exec -it 85e4df16a429 influx user password -n admin -t xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
? Please type your new password *********************
? Please type your new password again *********************
Your password has been successfully updated.

$
```

Comment: there is no other way to get the token?, I just used `influx setup` but where is the token after that?, can I get it without UI, but not reading this bolt file?

Answer (score 2):

It happened the same to me, I created a user and then I forgot the password.

For those who work in Windows, go to C:\Users\YourName and delete .influxdbv2.

[image: InfluxDB]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot i created a new user, organization and bucket when first running influxdb.
I've managed to solve it by purging all the influxdb files by running `dpkg --purge influxdb2` and then reinstalling.